# Alternatives to getCurrentposition?

Tags: javascript, html, api, geolocation

I have been working on an app that uses the getCurrentPosition(), but that doesn't work anymore in the latest version of Chrome, see:

[Deprecating Powerful Features on Insecure Origins](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins)

So my code here doesn't work in latest stable version of Chrome:

```
var latitude = 0;

var longitude = 0;

  if (navigator.geolocation) { 

   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

     latitude = position.coords.latitude;

     longitude = position.coords.longitude;

     $("#data").html("latitude: " + latitude + "<br>longitude: " + longitude);

   }); 

  }
```

What are alternatives to getting the user's position with HTML Geolocation API? Any thoughts?

Comment: As far as I understand you just have to use it in a secure origin (HTTPS).

Answer (score 0):

I'm grappling with this myself. If HTTPS is not an option for you, then maybe add a fallback for Chrome where you prompt the user to submit their address. Then have your app geocode it.